# Is the word "Until" used to show entailment?

Tags: semantics

Is the word "Until" used to show entailment? For eg.: An event doesn't happen until the third day. Does it entail that the event happens on the third day? Is there a possibility that the event may not happen on the third day? Can I say that the event does not happen on Day 1 or Day 2 and it may or may not happen or Day 3?

Comment: If I say that the event doesn't happen until the third day, I mean that to the best of my knowledge, the event is taking place on the third day. Whether it may or may not happen is out of the question because the only way it won't happen is if the world is attacked by an alien race, destroyed by a comet or catastrophe or at war, but that is understood. So, you can say that the event doesn't happen on days 1 and 2 but on the third day.

Comment: Consider the idiom: [*"Until hell freezes over."*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/until+hell+freezes+over)

Answer (score 1):

**Used in that sense of a future event, yes. I believe it does, provided the event is one that is determinable.**

If I say *He will never understand children until he becomes a father*, it does not involve entailment since he may never become a father.

Or we could say *We will not know the truth about her until she dies*. That would imply entailment, since death is inevitable. But *until she marries* wouldn't; since she may never marry.

However if I say *He is not going to France until next month* it definitely implies that there are firm plans for him to travel. That is because *next month* is something inevitable, which must happen, and cannot be avoided.

If one wants to use *until* in a non-entailed sense with a definite time condition, one would need to qualify it in some way - such as, *He will not go to London until Friday, at the earliest*. Or *If she visits her brother it will not be until Saturday*.

Comment: Quoting, "If I say He will never understand children until he becomes a father, it does not involve entailment since he may never become a father." Can we say that he DEFINITELY WILL be able to understand children once he becomes a father? How about this instance : There is an event which may or may not happen every day. Is, "Probability that the event does not occur until the third day," the same as, "Probability that the event does not occur on first day or second day and occurs on the third day"?

Comment: @MihirKelekar In "he definitely will be able to understand children once he becomes a father," there are two events:understanding children and becoming a father. The "understanding children" part is made sure because you have use "definitely" but the "becoming father" part is not determined to happen because it is characterized by "once, " which implies uncertainty to some extent. If it were "after he becomes a father" then the event is guaranteed because "after" is and should used if he is bound to become a father, which may be because the wife is pregnant, he has adopted a kid and the kid is

Comment: +1. But even in the statements where the the condition is not certain to happen, there's still a strong suggestion that the intent of the whole statement is that *if and when* it does, the assertion follows. That is, 'entailment' still applies.

Comment: You can also use, for example, "It will not be ready *until at least* Friday."  It *may* be ready on Friday; it may not be ready until sometime next week - but it *will be ready sometime* in the future.

Comment: @Lawrence Agreed. Then I think the determination of actual intent boils down to the actual context it is used in. In isolation, many arguments are and can be raised. Don't you think?

Comment: @vickyace If I understand your comment correctly, you're saying that without context, it can be hard to gauge the intent behind a statement. I would agree with that.

Comment: @vickyace I think that we can say to the OP, that in the absence of other qualification, and especially where the time is determinedly specified, that entailment is implied.

Comment: @WS2 Touche. Implied(maybe with possibility of improbability)

Comment: @MihirKelekar No, we can't say he will definitely understand children. But the use of *until* suggests that the speaker sees is as at least highly likely. *Until* always leans toward entailment. But of course people exaggerate things *As Arsenal are only playing Fleetwood United they cannot fail to win*. The words deem inevitability, but we all know that is not the case. *He will not be a better man until he becomes a father* is in that sort of category. But where the time is determinable, entailment is more than implied. The rest of your comment, I believe, has more to do with logic.

Comment: I can't tell if this is a discussion about *entail* or about *until*. I would say that *until* can enable entailment (by removing a condition that prevents it), but the source of the entailment comes from other context, not from the word *until*. So first, set up the entailment logic, and then remove the inhibiting condition with *until*. This seems to be how it is normally used. A counter example might be - "Can you play on Friday?", "We are engaged until Saturday". There isn't any entailment here. It's just answering "No" and suggesting Saturday might work. The necessary logic is missing.

Comment: @PhilSweet Yes, I see what you are saying. *I am not going on holiday until I have got a car*. Entailment is being prevented, but will be made possible, once I have a car. I agree. But I don't think this undermines the OP's question. Whether or not *until* indicates entailment is still a valid question, in my opinion.